# what does "not if" mean here?

Tags: verbs, conditional-constructions

If I said,

> "Jonathan **ignore me not** if I speak."

Does this mean:

> "Jonathan  **do not ignore me** if I speak."

Or does it mean:

> "If  I don't speak, Jonathan may or may not ignore me."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't say "ignore me not" nowadays: we say "don't ignore me."

Perhaps you found the sentence in an old book. In which case, yes: your interpretation is quite correct.

It is the language of the 1611 translation of the Bible (*go not in the way of evil men.*) and of Shakespeare (*Come not near our fairy queen.*) but was old-fashioned when John F. Kennedy said, *Ask not what your country can do for you.*

The old  word-order is preserved in the name of a flower: forget-me-not.